# How to use Powershell to Monitor a specific inbox for Commands?

Tags: scripting, powershell, outlook, imap

I would like to set up functionality where a powershell script would access the email in a specific mailbox.  It would then parse each email to engage in dialog with a specific set of users.  To serve as a system that could be interacted with through email.  How could this be pulled off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run this from a client with Outlook installed then the following is a good starting point (EWS is not required).

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$inbox | gm
```

Comment: Did you ever "encounter" the annoying popup (Office 2003) that this solution might produce when reading/sending emails? Thanks

Comment: Assuming the message is similar to 'another program is trying to send mail on your behalf', this is relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885682 (Check the registry key info)