# Reading email in MS Outlook

Tags: email, scripting, outlook

this one is of clumsy implementation type and I have small knowledge about MS products.

Task: Access MS Exchange Server (outlook or whatever) and parse all unread emails with specific sent date, subject, from address. Certain data should be saved during parsing (like a flag/boolean array or something similar)

Requirements: should be done either through scripting language (no matter which one, looks like VBS suits this task) or any other method that will be able to perform slight analysis and return an exit code and a message (I'm thinking about web services that might exist in OWA, or any thing else).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560490/how-to-use-powershell-to-monitor-a-specific-inbox-for-commands/3573593#3573593) on how to access outlook emails using Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a driver or dll for you language of choice, I know C# / VB have libraries to accomplish this. A web server is fine if its going to not be a headache setting up access between servers, or if its on the same box with permissions.

Should do the trick, I would personally use C# as it would make this incredibly easy with the .net libraries and OLEDrivers.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, is it possible to write an app(using C#) that will perform all the needed stuff **and** which can be called from a windows script which in turn will return a message? (why so clumsy -> this will be triggered remotely from a linux box)